# Firefox scrolling slow (Mac OS X, 3.5.4)

Tags: macos, firefox

If I do a two-finger gesture, it takes about two seconds until the Firefox window scrolls, and then it is immediate and not an incremental scroll.

Is this a known issue? Could it be a plugin (I don't have anything too non-standard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd recommend upgrading to the current version of Firefox and then see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Still present in 3.5.8

Answer (score 0):

I'd say changing the size of the website always works for me. make is smaller or bigger with Command and + or -

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new profile (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager#Mac_OS_X), if the issue is not present with the new profile than very probably your current profile is in some way "corrupted", maybe because of some extension.